# Connection refused after connection timeout - Remote Java debugging

Tags: java, websphere, remote-debugging

I have a Websphere server with remote debugging enabled.
Sometimes, when I try to connect to my debugger, I get:

> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timeout.

After I receive this message, I always get:

> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

How can I restart the connection state without restarting Websphere?

Comment: You might want to double check that the debugger is indeed started and that you are connecting to correct debugging port, you should be able to find it out in the logs.

Comment: Debugger is started and port is correct.
I can debug, disconnect, try to reconnect and get this error.